# Delete irrelevent text editor tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331848/how-to-display-dataframes) today, and the OP said I am using Sublime 3, but the problem is not relevant to his/her editor, so should I delete *I use Sublime Text 3* sentence and `sublimetext3` tag?

Comment: The edit you made was appropriate. The answers seem to find some relevance in the IDE, but not enough that the tag was needed. The question wasn't about the IDE itself.

Comment: This my Nth question that been duplicate in Meta , I have serious problems in finding similar questions here.

Comment: No worries, sometimes the right keywords escape us.